# dc.js: Multiple graphs in a single dimension

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

How do I create multiple graphs that graph one dimension such that they react to filters placed on the other graph.  Example here:  http://bl.ocks.org/pbutler/9356548

```
<html>
<head>
     <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="dc.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="crossfilter.js"></script>
    <script src="dc.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart1">
    </div>
    <div id="chart2">
    </div>
    <script>
        var data = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            data.push({'val' : 'a'})
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            data.push({'val' : 'b'})
        }

        var ndx = crossfilter(data);
        var all = ndx.groupAll();

        var val = ndx.dimension(function (d) { return d.val; });
        var valGroup = val.group()

        var chart1 = dc.pieChart("#chart1");
        var chart2 = dc.pieChart("#chart2");

        chart1.dimension(val)
          .group(valGroup);
        chart2.dimension(val)
        .group(valGroup);

        dc.renderAll();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In short the graphs seem to ignore each other in this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the answer can be found here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dc-js-user-group/1nIScnbY0vs .  There are two possible ways, add another dimension as suggested by DJ Martin or use an on("click", ...) handler to call the filter on the second chart.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a second dimension using the same property, the filtering will reflect across charts.

Here is an example of that: http://jsfiddle.net/djmartin_umich/nw8EV/.

```
// build charts
teamMemberChart
    .width(270)
    .height(220)
    .dimension(teamMemberDimension)
    .group(teamMemberGroup)
    .valueAccessor(function (d) {
    return d.value.projectCount;
})
    .elasticX(true);

teamMemberChart2
    .width(270)
    .height(220)
    .dimension(teamMemberDimension)
    .group(teamMemberGroup)
    .valueAccessor(function (d) {
    return d.value.projectCount;
})
    .elasticX(true);

teamMemberChart3
    .width(270)
    .height(220)
    .dimension(teamMemberDimension2)
    .group(teamMemberGroup2)
    .valueAccessor(function (d) {
    return d.value.projectCount;
})
    .elasticX(true);
```

The first two charts use the same dimension - picking one option does not reflect the other. The third chart uses a different dimension on the same property - choosing an option on this chart updates the other two charts.

Comment: I guess what I didn't explain very well was that I don't want the filtering to be applied to the second chart.  I just wanted the hilighting to be applied.  My example was simplified but the application that I was trying to achieve was was a pie chart / choropleth combination that will select the area of interest if it is selected in the pie chart.